# Weird CMD batch script reporting of %errorlevel%

Tags: oracle, batch-file, cmd, sqlplus, errorlevel

In the script below, when there is a sql error, `%errorlevel%` is 0 - why is this?

```
IF %RELEASE% GTR 2 (
    (
    echo WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
    echo @release.sql
    echo exit
    ) | sqlplus x/x@orcl
    echo error: %errorlevel%
    if %errorlevel% gtr 0 goto dberror
)
```

If I remove the if block (below) then %errorlevel% is NON zero!  Why does the if statement affect the error level?

```
    (
    echo WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
    echo @release.sql
    echo exit
    ) | sqlplus x/x@orcl
    echo error: %errorlevel%
    if %errorlevel% gtr 0 goto dberror
```

---

**Update**: Believe it was the way I was testing for an error.  I think instead of:

```
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 goto dberror
```

..  should be using:

```
if errorlevel 1 goto dberror
```

Useful link [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php)

Comment: Yes indeed. `if errorlevel 1` actually means `if errorlevel is 1 or greater`. Errorlevel isn't and environment variable. It represents the exit code of the last executed process and has its own little if syntax. :D

Comment: @GolezTrol: It does have its own syntax for checks but is an environment variable as well and can be used just like any other variable: echoing, checking value, passing as a parameter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sigh. It's all to do with the horrible dos parsing, and the point at which *cmd* replaces `%errorlevel%` with its value. When you enclose commands with `(`...`)`, *cmd* first reads in those commands as though they were all written on one line, expanding variables as it goes. Thus in your first code block, `%errorlevel%` is replaced by its value *when the block is parsed*. It's as if you wrote:

```
IF 3 GTR 2 (
   (
   echo WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
   echo @release.sql
   echo exit
   ) | sqlplus x/x@orcl
   echo error: 0
   if 0 gtr 0 goto dberror
)
```

(assuming `$RELEASE` was 3). The reason your `if errorlevel` fix works is that `cmd` does not do any (too) early variable expansion on that re-formulation. You can use `call` to avoid this problem:

```
IF %RELEASE% GTR 2 (
    (
    echo WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
    echo @release.sql
    echo exit
    ) | sqlplus x/x@orcl
    call echo error: %%errorlevel%%
    call if %%errorlevel%% gtr 0 goto dberror
)
```

(which I think is clearer than `startlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `!errorlevel!`—YMMV of course).

Comment: P.S. It's possible to set errorlevel to a negative number(!), so `NEQ 0` is the most comprehensive test. (I feel another sigh coming on.)